# Read text from TextBuffer in pyGtk using TextMarks

Tags: python, buffer, pygtk

I am using a multiline text view and a text buffer to manipulate text in pyGtk. I want to read input from the position from which an insert was pressed the last time, and the current position where the insert is pressed again.

```
def markit(self, pos):
    mark = self.create_mark(mark_name = 'StartInsert', where = pos, left_gravity = True)
    mark.set_visible = True
    return mark

def keyPress(widget, event):
if event.keyval == 65293:
    buff = termwindow.get_buffer()
    # Read the command.

    ### How to do this?????

    print command
    # Delete previous created Mark.
    buff.delete_mark_by_name('StartInsert')
    buff.markit(current_pos)
    return True
return False
```

This is the mark I create every time in the Enter key callback function. Initially, this position can be zero. Also, though I did set the visibility True, Its not visible.